# Get scala template in a variable in Play Framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework

Lets say there are two scala templates in view folder

1. file1.scala.html
2. container.scala.html

Now I want to pass first template into 2nd template (container.scala.html) from controller. Like:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    static Result isItPossible()
    {
        Result theFile=ok(file1.render());
        return ok(container.render(theFile));
    }
}
```

Is it possible? If it is, How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a rendered template to the `container` template. `container` would need to have some `Html` parameter:

container.scala.html:

```
@(content: Html)

<p>Here's my content: @content </p>
```

And from within the controller:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    return ok(container.render(file1.render()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to mention that you don't need to combine your *wrapping containers* in the controller, as template engine has an ability to use **Layouts** for it ([as described in docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases)). In that case you can use it like that:

**container.scala.html**

```
@()(content: Html)
<p>Here's my content: @content </p>
```

**file1.scala.html**

```
@container() {
    <b>this is content of <i>file1</i> template</b>
}
```

**controller**

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    static Result itIsPossible() {
        return ok(file1.render());
    }
}
```